# Variable value conversion from any case to smaller case in psql CLI

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

I was creating a script to create DB user in Postgres via psql CLI, the challanges I am facing is that value conversion from Any case to lower case is happeing or not able to find the solution for the same.

```
\prompt 'Please input user name (must be lowercase): ' inputName
\set lowerVal lower(:inputName)    --This is not working
```

As per my expectation the lowerVal variable should convert the inputValue into lower case value.
Did the googles but didn't got the solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` cannot to evaluate expressions, so your example cannot to work. You can use statement `\gset`, that evaluate query and stores a result to `psql` variable:

```
postgres=# \prompt 'Please input user name (must be lowercase): ' inputName
Please input user name (must be lowercase): AHOJ
postgres=# select lower(:'inputName') as "inputName" \gset 
postgres=# \echo :inputName
ahoj
```

Probably is better to use only small chars for `psql` variable names.

Another possibility is using shell expression evaluation with back apostrophes:

```
postgres=# \set str AHOJ
postgres=# \set str `echo ":str" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
postgres=# \echo :str
ahoj
```

This example works on Unix like systems only.